# Taking ownership of remote registry keys in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, registry

I need to take ownership of a remote registry key across the network in order to delete it but I'm struggling to work out how.  PSRemoting is turned off and needing to download additional software etc to do so is untenable (this is part of a toolset script that is used by multiple teams).

Thus far I've tried doing it using REGINI but always get the same error

```
REGINI: CreateKey (\\computername\HKU\SID\software\microsoft\windows NT\currentversion\windows) relative to handle (000000000) failed - 161
REGINI: Failed to load from file 'acl.txt' (161)
```

Has anyone else had the need to do this and found a good solution?

Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend using Group Policy to manage registry keys on computers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried psexec  in conjunction with the regini command?

```
psexec -s \\computername regini c:\temp\acl.txt
```

Don't forget to copy the acl.txt to target computer's  c:\temp folder.